# How do I Change Hint on selecting different radio buttons?

Tags: android, radio-button

I have created 3 radio buttons. There are 2 edittext fields and one dropdown. there will be hint diplayed on but edit texts and dropdown too. By default the hints of the first button should be displayed. right now the dropdown is between the two text fields. On selecting the second button i want the hints to change and the dropdown should be on top of both the edittexts. How do i do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e5e5e5">


<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.90"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_recharge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_bills"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="DTH"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_transfer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:text="DataCard"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>


</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Mobile Number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Recharge Amount"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set hints to edit text you can use setHint("hint text") method.

you can have one more edit text in between spinner and bottom edit text with a visibility set to gone  .
On second radio button checked make visibility top most edit text gone and make visible the edit text between the spinner and bottom edit text